# way to use the jobs inside jenkins, when jenkins server shut down

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

we have a scheduler: instances goes down by 8pm and comes up by 11 am.
if dev team requires a server/instance and comes to ops team saying that they need a particular instances to run till 12am or 1 am and vice-versa, ops team should do it manually

so I came up with the solution that I can use jenkins server and configure job to start and stop the instances (extend or prepone the particular instances)

The problem is I have configured the jobs inside the jenkins server but this server will shut down at 8 pm

if jenkins server comes down by 8pm how can we use the jobs inside that jenkins server? is there any possible way that we can configure the same start and stop of the ec2 instances other than jenkins

Comment: Sounds pretty clear to me that you need something that is running 24/7, if it needs to coordinate the starting & stopping of other servers. Either your own server, or any kind of saas etc. tool that can handle this.

Comment: can you please give me clear idea @james-zea